# OpenTK based/compatible text rendering library

Tags: .net, opentk, text-rendering

I noticed an example for text rendering in the OpenTK documentation, but is there a library that has already been developed for this purpose? I am looking to use this for a video game, so it does need to be as performant as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTK used to have a very good TextPrinter class included. It's still there, but it's deprecated now, so it resides in the OpenTK.Compatibility DLL (which is included in the main installation). They deprecated it because they didn't want to maintain it anymore, I think. If they ever drop it from OpenTK, you'll be able to take the code from its last release and maintain it yourself.

OpenTK's TextPrinter works fine in my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [OpenTK.Text](http://www.opentk.com/project/text) but it is easier to just use System.Drawing to render text to an image and render that [as described in the documentation](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/how-to-render-text-using-opengl).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a download link for OpenTK.Text. I guess there aren't any other libraries; I suppose I will have to make my own.

Comment: Followup note (1.5f years later): the linked OpenTK sample relies on immediate mode, which has been deprecated.